# How to convert bullet points into horizontal list?

Tags: html, css, list

I want to show disc bullet points in my horizontal list.

I know that once we define in CSS: `display: inline;`, the class definition: `list-style-type: disc` does not work.

So this has been my solution:

```
                <ul>
                    <li>· EN</li>
                    <li>· ES</li>
                    <li>· ES</li>
                    <li>· DE</li>
                    <li>· FR</li>
                </ul>
```

I have put the symbol disc bullet point manually in my horizontal list and then I have declared that in my head section: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`.

In My coda editor preview they look fine, but if i try to browser it I get � this.

Why? How can I figure it out the problem? Otherwise, what is the best solution to show disc bullet point in a horizontal list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of choosing `display:inline` for your `li` you could keep them as blocks and do this:

```
li {
    float:left; 
}
```

Then you could play with the margins to space them how you need.

Comment: This by itself does not fully work if you want the list with bullets. The first bullet is o.k. but for the rest, the bullets display on top of the words from the previous item on the list. i.e. the bullet for the third item displays on the word for the 2nd item, and so on. I corrected this by adding `margin-right:30px;` to the `li` element. I would assume there are other solutions, which I would be interested in hearing, as I would prefer one that doesn't require me to specify a specific pixel amount but rather a percentage or a way in which the spacing is dependent on something else.

Answer (score 6):

Try **display:inline-block**

**CSS**

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To work in IE6 and IE7:

**CSS**

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: I still advise floating left than displaying as inline-block because older versions of IE can have problems displaying block elements as inline-block elements.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with you approach is twofold. First, the character “·” you are using is not a bullet; it is the MIDDLE DOT with multiple usage, mainly as a separator in texts. The BULLET “•” character is more suitable. Second, you are declaring UTF-8, which is fine, but then you document needs to be UTF-8 encoded in reality, and it apparently is (rather, looking from here, it is probably windows-1252 encoded).

But as a quick fix that does not require a solution to the encoding problem, you can write BULLET using the entity reference `&bull;`, e.g. `<li>&bull;&nbsp;EN</li>`.

There are of course other approaches, too. But if you set `display: inline`, then browsers will not generate bullets, as they do that only for elements that that `display: list-item`. You would need to include the bullets into the element content, or to use generated content (using the `:before` pseudo-element).